# RewriteCond with the famous !-f and !-d conditions is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `.htaccess` file with the following directives:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /amit/public/
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [OR]
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Pretty basic redirection. However, I'm getting an infinite internal loop in my apache log files with a 500 error in the browser. The apache log file has the following:

```
r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/activities.php
redirected from r->uri = /activities.php
```

That's when I enter the page with the extension. Makes no difference when I try to access the page without the extension. The page exists and I've double checked everything, but it seems to me that the main issue is the RewriteCond.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 4 conditions and need to have them ANDed together:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /amit/public/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still not breaking the loop. I've tried different variations including this one.

Comment: It is the complete file.

Comment: Wait, I think I just found the problem. Let me test out the variations `%` and `$` after the `RewriteCond`

Comment: Try my updated code and also tell your URI causing this 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @anubhava. I've just realized that my code uses `$` for all the server variables. It should be `%`. A silly typo had hacked my brain for close to 24 hours... So the 'ultimate' code with the suggestions made by @anubhava would be:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /amit/public/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Please avoid posting an answer to your question based on another answer. You don't need `-s` and `-l` conditions